# Pass value via one specific link from a loop-generated list of links via sessions

Tags: php, session, hyperlink, session-variables

- I try to pass a value (or a few values) from site A to site B.
- In site A I'm generating a list of links.
- If someone clicks on any of those links, he/she will be on site B.
- On site B I want to display data depending on the link clicked. Therefore I have to pass variables via that link.

I know, that it's possible to pass the variables via that link (with GET,POST). However, I read that it's generally better to use sessions. (security issues, cleaner link, more transparent ...). But when I'm using sessions, I have to register session variables. How to handle that in my case. I have to register that session variable on click of that specific link. I didn't find anything like a link-listener for PHP. (I guess it's possible with JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

By "from site A to site B" I think you mean by "webpage A to webpage B" not "website A to website B"

You will need to write this line at top of each page before any html output

```
<?php
 session_start();
?>
```

in page a.php
write

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 'this is session test';
?>
```

and in page b.php
you write

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>

Now load page b.php after loading page a.php.
```

Comment: How would I register a session variable for a special link...?

Comment: I know how sessions are working :) But, imagine 10 links created in a loop. I needed to register a session variable for every of the 10 links. But I only want to have a session variable for the link one has clicked on.